# Node.js http.get vs google chrome $.get, difference in speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, xmlhttprequest

So I was messing around in node.js and ran this code :

```
var http = require("http");

function get() {
    var headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
    };
    var startedAt = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        http.get({
            host: "www.example.net",
            path: "/catalog/",
            header: headers
        }, function (response) {
            var body;
            response.on('data', function (d) {});
            response.on('end', function (e) {
                console.log(new Date().getTime() - startedAt);
            });
        });
}
get()
```

I discovered it is almost 3x slower than `GET` request over Google Chrome extensions. I have copied the headers exactly, yet there is still almost a 100ms difference in speed.

Any ideas how to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding times around 50ms/request with your same logic so I'm going to assume you are running this loop many times and taking an average. If that is the case then you are probably running a version of node < 0.12 and http.globalAgent.maxSockets has a default of 5 (which is only allowing 5 concurrent connections at a time in your case).
Try setting `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;` as the setting is in current versions of Node.